# Sorting and listing according to the fields that user selects

Tags: php, sql

I have

- Employee Name
- Project Name
- Task Type
- Work Type
- Date From
- Date To

this is what i used for selecting the fields from DB.

```
$slct_sort=" SELECT
                  a.`title`, b.`name`, c.`name` AS `staff_name`, d. `work_types`
             FROM
                 `task_type` a, `project_details` b,  `staff_details` c, `work_types` d
           ";
```

I need to Display The results according to the user selection. If they leave any field, particular 'SHOULD NOT' be sorted.

Comment: I suppose `ORDER BY task_type` etc... should work. It's just a matter of dynamically constructing your query.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3YRm5H73g9STEYzU216UDVPdkE/edit?usp=drive_web

see the link... You will get an idea.

Comment: If the user selects only 2 fields, should it select only two?

Comment: It can select all But the result should be only according to that two fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps:

1. Set value field in drop down with what columns in database.
2. Use j Query Ajax when you change value from Drop Down and get currently selected one.
3. Change the query term ORDER BY field with currently selected option.

-

Thanks